# Paying Video on iPhone Safari

Tags: iphone, safari, video-streaming, spring-rest

We  have custom web application and serves Video content. We have successfully playing video content on Web Browsers but not on iPhone Safari, Google and Firefox browsers.

I have received input saying, media server need to support content Ranges. So over come this issue, we have created custom Spring Rest api and downloaded video content into input stream. We are checking, if the request is from iPhone device, send the Partial Content response.

@RequestMapping(value = "{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public final ResponseEntity retrieveResource(@PathVariable(value = "key") final String key,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Range", required = false) String range,
            @RequestHeader(value = PortalParam.USER_AGENT, required = false) String userAgent) throws Exception {
        log.info("Range \t" + range);
        log.info("User Agent \t" + userAgent);

```
    long rangeStart = 0L;
    long rangeEnd = 0L;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Expires", "0");
    headers.set("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
    headers.set("Connection", "keep-alive");

    headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, "bytes");
    headers.set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    // .openStream();

    URL myURL = new URL("my URL");
    HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();

    long contentLength = myURLConnection.getContentLength(); 

    InputStream inputStream = myURLConnection.getInputStream();

    if (range != null && (userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") != -1 ||  userAgent.indexOf("curl") != -1 )) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayInputStream inStream = null;
        String rangeValue = range.trim().substring("bytes=".length());
        String myvideo = key.replaceAll(".mp4", "") + "_" + new RandomString(12).nextString();
        String outputFile = PortalParam.getRandomAccessFile() + PortalParam.SLASH + myvideo + ".part";
        myvideo = myvideo + ".mp4";

        long start, end;
        if (rangeValue.startsWith("-")) {
            end = contentLength - 1;
            start = contentLength - 1 - Long.parseLong(rangeValue.substring("-".length()));
        } else {
            String[] myrange = rangeValue.split("-");
            start = Long.parseLong(myrange[0]);
            end = myrange.length > 1 ? Long.parseLong(myrange[1]) : contentLength - 1;
        }
        if (end > contentLength - 1) {
            end = contentLength - 1;
        }
        if (start <= end) {
            contentLength = end - start + 1;
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, contentLength + "");
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE, "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + contentLength);
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    //      headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=" + myvideo);


            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*8];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int totalRead = 0;
            log.info("Content Length \t" + contentLength);
            while (((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, (int)start, (int)contentLength)) > 0) && (totalRead < contentLength)) {
                log.info("BUffer Read \t" + bytesRead);
                totalRead = totalRead + bytesRead;
                log.info("Total Read \t" + totalRead);
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            log.info("Total Read \t" + totalRead);
            //inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
        }

         headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("video/mp4"));

        log.info("Headers \t" + headers.toString());
        InputStream myStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(myStream), headers, HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT);
    } else {
        log.info("Headers \t" + headers.toString());
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("video/mp4"));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(inputStream), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The curl request is giving following output
curl -k --range 0-99 https://example.com/mycontent/myvideo.mp4 -o /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   100  100   100    0     0    237      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   243

curl -k --range 0-99 https://example.com/mycontent/myvideo.mp4
gives
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Wed, 04 Sep 2019 16:37:46 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: 0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 0-99/100
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 100

Here is the response we are getting, when accessing from the server.

2019-09-04 16:38:33 INFO  VideoStreamer:77 - User Agent         Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
2019-09-04 16:38:33 INFO  VideoStreamer:136 - Content Length    2
2019-09-04 16:38:33 INFO  VideoStreamer:138 - BUffer Read       2
2019-09-04 16:38:33 INFO  VideoStreamer:140 - Total Read        2
2019-09-04 16:38:33 INFO  VideoStreamer:143 - Total Read        2
2019-09-04 16:38:33 INFO  VideoStreamer:159 - Headers   [Expires:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store", Connection:"keep-alive", Accept-Ranges:"bytes", Content-Transfer-Encoding:"binary", Content-Length:"2", Content-Range:"bytes 0-1/2", Content-Type:"video/mp4"]

Still not able to render video on iPhone Safari. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The value after the slash in Content-Range should be the size of the object, not the size of the range

Comment: Thanks @szatmary and corrected the issue. We are getting length of the video but no Audio and Video